# Created nested model setting a property on nested model before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models a `Company` and a `User` the Company `has_many :users` and the User `belongs_to :company`.  I have a form such as:

`<%= form_for @company, data: {toggle: :validator}, novalidate: "novalidate", html: {role: :form} do |f| %>`

**company fields**

Then in there I have

`<%= f.fields_for :users, @company.users.build do |user_form| %>`

**A bunch of user fields**

It posts the data with the nested attributes of `users_attributes: {"0" => {name: "Chad"}}`

But it doesn't create the user only the company object.

**Company Model**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :contacts, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts

  attr_accessor :card_token, :users_attributes

  before_create :create_company_customer_token
  before_create :create_admin_user
  before_destroy :set_deleted_flag

  validates_presence_of :name, :phone_number

  private

  def create_admin_user
    self.users.first.admin = true
  end

  def set_deleted_flag
    self.deleted = true
    save

    users.each do |u|
      u.destroy
    end

    false
  end

  def create_company_customer_token
    begin
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: "Company: #{self.name}", card: self.card_token, plan: self.plan)
      self.stripe_customer_id = customer['id']
    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
      self.errors.add(:stripe_customer_id, "Looks like we are having an issue at the moment, please try again shortly")
      @logger ||= Rails.logger
      @logger.error(e)
    end
  end

end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
include Clearance::User

  has_many :messages
  belongs_to :company

  before_destroy :set_deleted_flag
  after_create :send_welcome_email

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, scope: :company_id, conditions: -> { where.not(deleted: true) }

  def name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

  private

  def set_deleted_flag
    self.deleted = true
    save
  end

  def send_welcome_email
    UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you post your both models? Do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :users` in `Company` model? And also post your full form code.

Comment: Yea I do Ill post my models

Comment: I was able to make it work by doing `@company.users.build(user_params)` in the `CompaniesController` but I felt there was a more *Railsish* way.